# unmarshall string to java object using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, type-conversion, jaxb

I'm using JAXB unmarshaller to convert xml string to java object, however I get an error that I don't know what does that mean

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL", local:"definitions"). Expected elements are <{}bpmn:definitions>
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1106)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:531)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3079)
```

The xml I'm using is something like this

```
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:modeler="http://camunda.org/schema/modeler/1.0" id="Definitions_1xqdoqa" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="5.13.0" modeler:executionPlatform="Camunda Platform" modeler:executionPlatformVersion="7.19.0">
  <bpmn:process id="Process2" isExecutable="true" camunda:historyTimeToLive="1">
    <bpmn:userTask id="Activity_0r63cqs">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow02</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_0xsmp8q</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:userTask>
    <bpmn:userTask id="Activity_0e7h96z">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:taskListener class="ir.edmp.camunda.listeners.EDMPTaskCreateListener" event="create">
          <camunda:field name="assigneeType">
            <camunda:string>Static</camunda:string>
          </camunda:field>
          <camunda:field name="assigneeApproach">
            <camunda:string>admin_platform</camunda:string>
          </camunda:field>
        </camunda:taskListener>
....
```

My java class is BPMNDefinition

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "bpmn:definitions")
public class BPMNDefinitions {
    private String bPMN;
    private String xPMNDI;
    private String dC;
    private String camunda;
    private String xSI;
    private String dI;
    private String modeler;
    private String id;
    private String targetNameSpace;
    private String exporter;
    private String exporterVersion;
    private String executionPlatform;
    private String executionPlatformVersion;

    public String getbPMN() {
        return bPMN;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setbPMN(String bPMN) {
        this.bPMN = bPMN;
    }

    public String getxPMNDI() {
        return xPMNDI;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setxPMNDI(String xPMNDI) {
        this.xPMNDI = xPMNDI;
    }

    public String getdC() {
        return dC;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setdC(String dC) {
        this.dC = dC;
    }

    public String getCamunda() {
        return camunda;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setCamunda(String camunda) {
        this.camunda = camunda;
    }

    public String getxSI() {
        return xSI;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setxSI(String xSI) {
        this.xSI = xSI;
    }

    public String getdI() {
        return dI;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setdI(String dI) {
        this.dI = dI;
    }

    public String getModeler() {
        return modeler;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setModeler(String modeler) {
        this.modeler = modeler;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTargetNameSpace() {
        return targetNameSpace;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setTargetNameSpace(String targetNameSpace) {
        this.targetNameSpace = targetNameSpace;
    }

    public String getExporter() {
        return exporter;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setExporter(String exporter) {
        this.exporter = exporter;
    }

    public String getExporterVersion() {
        return exporterVersion;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setExporterVersion(String exporterVersion) {
        this.exporterVersion = exporterVersion;
    }

    public String getExecutionPlatform() {
        return executionPlatform;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setExecutionPlatform(String executionPlatform) {
        this.executionPlatform = executionPlatform;
    }

    public String getExecutionPlatformVersion() {
        return executionPlatformVersion;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setExecutionPlatformVersion(String executionPlatformVersion) {
        this.executionPlatformVersion = executionPlatformVersion;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm unmarshalling the string

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, JAXBException {
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8081/engine-rest/process-definition/key/Process2/xml");
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        JSONObject firstTaskFlows = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        String xmlString = firstTaskFlows.get("bpmn20Xml").toString();
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BPMNDefinitions.class);
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        BPMNDefinitions customer = (BPMNDefinitions) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    }
```

By the way, I'm trying to get xml response from camunda (BPMN Engine) and convert it to java object

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error since your @XmlRootElement misses the XML namespace (xmlns) but since your XML documents contains a lot of child elements with different namespaces I doubt adding this would be enough. Usually you would start with the XML schema of BPMN and generate Java classes out of it.

I think another option in this special case would be not to use JAXB but the [Camunda Model API](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/read-a-model/).

Another thing: Do yourself a favor and never convert between XML documents, which come as byte array usually, and String using `new String()` or `String.getBytes()`. If you do this without watching the character set within the XML declaration of your document, or UTF-8 if its missing, you'll get mangled characters sooner or later. Every conversion between byte [] and String either assumes a character set or encoding (default platform encoding) or expects it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, but the thing is I'm trying to create a custom application that uses REST API to get data from Camunda, so I can't use Camunda Model API, Is there another way to easily get data, like Inputs and Outputs or attributes of an activity. for example in a Process I have like 50 Activities and I want to get Inputs and Outputs of each activity, I don't think calling api over and over is ok

Comment: I have two approaches in mind. First approach is take the BPMN-Schema to generate Java classes out of it and then use JAXB to convert the XML document into Java objects. Second approach is to use a XSL transformation to first extract the relevent information into a second XML document and then use JAXB to convert this into your own custom Java objects. I'd use the first approach but converting a XML Schema with many namespaces into Java classes may be a bit tricky.

Comment: Why not get the model verison and use the Model API on the client side?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of Camunda, just found the SAX parser on the API, which possibly may fulfill the demands. But I weren't sure about this.